# F4 onKeyPress with Internet Explorer doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have problem with jQuery `onKeyPress()` execution on IE9.

On Mozilla everything works fine, but IE9 makes problems.

When I set focus to a text area and press <kbd>F4</kbd>, I call a function to show div. That works fine in Mozilla, but in IE9 it does not. I tried many combinations with `onKeyDown`/`onKeyUp` but I didn't succeed.

Could you please help with a tested solution?

My code is:

```
$('#textBox).on('keypress', foo);

function foo() {
    var KEYCODE_F4 = 115;
    if (event.which == KEYCODE_F4) {
        someMethod();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think

```
function foo() {
    ...
}
```

Should be

```
function foo(event) {
    ...
}
```

As noted by [Barry Chapman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/655667/barry-chapman) you are also missing an `'` on your `$('#textBox')`

Comment: When I change KEYCODE_F4 to 13 (Enter) it works fine, but doesn't work for F4 (keycode 115)

Comment: Thank you very much, the problem was in "foo(event)"

Answer (score 0):

I hope its not because of this:

```
$('#textBox).on('keypress', foo);
           ^-missing a '
```

Should be:

```
$(document.body).on('keypress', '#textBox', function(event) {

   var KEYCODE_F4 = 115;
   if (event.which == KEYCODE_F4) {
       someMethod();
   }

});
```